# How to print a Link list onto separate lines

Tags: java, printing, linked-list

I have a list of names that have to be in a Link List and I am trying to print each name on to a separate lines

**What is printing**

```
[Bob, John, Kayla, Sam]
```

**What I am trying to get**

```
Bob
John
Kayla
Sam
```

---

```
private LinkedList<String> friend = new LinkedList<String>(); 


 for (int i = 0 ; i< profiles; i++)
    {   
    LinkedList<String> linkName = face.get(i).getFriend();      
    System.out.println("Status: " + linkName);

    }
```

Comment: How do you set the data into LinkedList? In your code, variable 'friend' is modified only once by "= new LinkedList<String>();", new object of LinkedList does not have data like "[Bob, John, Kayla, Sam]" in general.

Comment: The variable friend is not used. What is the purpose of it?
face.get(i).getFriend(); is returning linkedList.
So you have to iterate it to get the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the LinkedList and print it something like ...

```
LinkedList<String> linkName = face.get(i).getFriend();  
for (String name : linkName)    
    System.out.println(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list:

```
for(String item: friend){
    System.out.println(item);
}
```